# Phonegapped Android application not working as compared to HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, android, json, html, cordova

I made a HTML5 app, which accessess JSON data from a web service. The app works fine when opened in a browser on desktop computer, but when it is "phonegapped" into Android application it is not working. I have added following line on the PHP server to enable CORS:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Following is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
    <style>
        img {
            height: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="images"></div>
    <script>
        function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            // XDomainRequest for IE.
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            // CORS not supported.
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }
    function onMyClick() {
        console.info(new Object("Hello"));

        var url = 'http://example.com/mobile/index.php?tag=getAllById&catid=60';

        var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
        if (!xhr) {
            throw new Error('CORS not supported');
        }

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var responseText = xhr.responseText;
            console.info(responseText);
            // process the response.
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
             console.info('There was an error!');
        };
        xhr.send();
        console.info(new Object("Hello 4"));
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="onMyClick()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Not working as Android app means that I am getting, "There was an error!" message as the above line in onerror event prints, instead of the JSON data as response text, in the console of eclipse. Please could anyone help me get this working as Android application also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above example I can't see what is wrong but there are multiple possibilities.
The domain you are accessing might not be white listed in your config.xml? To allow everything include the following:
`<access origin="*" />`

See docs about white list for more info [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)

Another thing which comes to mind, your app needs internet connection to work, do you have the required permissions setup in AndroidManifest.xml?
You need to find the`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` declaration.

Comment: There was problem with internet connection. Actually I have 2 internet connections, so the tablet on which I was testing was connected to the internet connection which is not working, but the PC on which I was testing HTML5 application was connected to working internet connection & therefore it was working as HTML5 app but not as "Phonegapped" Android application.